# Reading image from a local temporary file using php

Tags: php, image

Scenario : Earlier I was reading the url of image directly and resized the image into 4 different size . But I had execution time out . Now I read the url and copy it into a temporary folder and pass the images in local temporary folder to imagecreatefromjpeg().

```
protected static function saveImage($row,$url){
    $percent = 1.0; 
    $imagethumbsize = 200;
    $db = PJFactory::getDbo();
    $details = $db->getImageDetails();
    $max = sizeof($details);
    $tempfilename = "C:".DS."xampp".DS."htdocs".DS."opg-uat".DS."img".DS."temp".DS.$row['CategoryID'].".jpg"; 
    $tempcopy = copy($url,$tempfilename);
   foreach ($details as $array) {
    $new_width=$array[2];
    $new_height=$array[3];
    $newfilename = "C:".DS."xampp".DS."htdocs".DS."opg-uat".DS."img".DS."c".DS.$row['CategoryID']."-".$array[1].".jpg"; 
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tempfilename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
    imagejpeg($image_p, $newfilename);
 }
 }
```

Error : The images are correctly being saved in temp folder . But in the destination folder images of all sizes are created but the image looks only black . (Not getting the actual image) . I guess there is some problem with the file reading from local . 
Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you reading images which are only JPG file only?

Comment: `$details = $db->getImageDetails();` how does that know which image to check sizes of? Also, following that, what does `var_dump($array)` show?

Comment: getImageDetails is a function I ve written from db . There are like 4 sizes the image needs to be resized . So this size .

Comment: Yes I am reading JPG file only . I did not get this error when I passed imagecreatefromjpeg($url) in this as it was global access .

Comment: Yes, but I assume that the sizes are going to be relative? So how does your function know what the starting sizes are? Or is it just always `100x100`, `300x300` etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read files other than `JPG` files, it will return only black images,
So while reading images, check which filetype your file really has and then call the correct function between the three (`jpeg`, `png`, `gif`).

Comment: The image I have copied from url to temp file is a JPG . So the temp file has JPG image only . Any better suggestions ?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382189/imagecreatefromjpeg-returns-a-black-image-after-resize

Answer (score 0):

Do you set `$width` and `$height` anywhere?

```
$width = imagesx($image);
$height= imagesy($image);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I did not set original width and height . Sorry